# Evaluating the Promt in Python Interactive Shell before displaying the prompt

Tags: python

It would be very convenient to have Python interactive shell show the current **time every time the prompt is displayed afresh**.  I am thinking of setting my prompt to something like: 
    sys.ps1 = str(datetime.datetime.now().time().isoformat()[:8])

Since the prompt is not evaluated every time it is displayed, this will only display the time at the creation of the shell and will not update it during its lifetime.

I use 3.5.1 version more frequently - in case that matters.

Is there a way to make shell evaluate the prompt string just before **each time the prompt is displayed**?

Thank your for your responses and time.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
import datetime

class Prompt():
    def __str__(self):
        return str(datetime.datetime.now().time().isoformat()[:8])

sys.ps1 = Prompt()
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html

```
If a non-string object is assigned to either variable, its str()
is re-evaluated each time the interpreter prepares to read a
new interactive command; this can be used to implement a
dynamic prompt.
```